# During table migration of tables from one tablespace to another, does it needs free space to do the alter table move?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, alter-table, disk-space, tablespaces

During migration of tables from one tablespace to another (all datafiles in the same disk/partition/mount), does it needs free space to do the alter table move?

exemple:. I have 30gb of free space on that disk, table of 1TB in tablespace_1, i wanna move the table using **alter table move** to tablespace_2.. can i do it or do i need to have more space available? if so, how much free space available?

Thx a lot :)

Comment: As Balasz indicated, there is no magic: you need space for both the new table copy and the original table copy. From what you say, both your existing and new tablespaces are on the same disk. My question then is: what's the point in moving that table to a new tablespace. What do you expect to achieve by doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table move copies the whole table into a new segment, then drops the old segment. This means you need enough space to store the old segment and the new segment at the same time. For a 1 TB table full of data, you need another 1 TB free space for the move to succeed.